# How to show standard deviation as a shape?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data frame `df`:

```
structure(list(queue = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("XXX1", 
"XXX2", "XXX3", "XXX4", 
"XXX5", "XXX6", "XXX7", 
"XXX8", "XXX9", "XXX10"), class = "factor"), 
    hour = c(8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13), num_at = c(5, 10.6923076923077, 
    8.35294117647059, 7.74285714285714, 10.0769230769231, 9.34615384615385
    ), num_wt = c(1.8, 8.28571428571429, 11.3478260869565, 11.2121212121212, 
    17.5185185185185, 6.68421052631579),num_wt_se = c(0.8, 0.25, 1.3, 1.4, 
    1.5, 2.6),num_at_se = c(1.2, 1.2, 1.3, 1.2, 
    1.1, 2.3)), .Names = c("queue", 
"hour", "num_at", "num_wt","num_at_se","num_wt_se"), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")
```

I created a chart with two line curves, the 1st corresponds to `num_wt`, while the 2nd corresponds to `num_at` values.

```
library("dplyr")
library("tidyr")
library("ggplot2")

p <- df[df$queue == "XXX1",] %>%
          gather(key, num, num_wt, num_at) %>%
          ggplot(aes(x=hour, y=num, colour=key)) +
          geom_smooth(span = 0.3) +
          scale_color_manual(labels = c("Line 1", "Line 2"), values = c("#F8AA5A", "#BD63BD")) +
          labs(title = "Title", 
               x = "Hour", 
               y = "Value",
               color = "")
p
```

Now I want to show the standard deviation for `num_wt` and `num_at` that is stored in `num_wt_se` and `num_at_se`, correspondingly. I would like to depict the standard deviation as a shape, not as lines. How can I do it?
I googled for a possible solution and found this one, however it shows nothing in my case:

`stat_smooth(method="loess", span=0.1, se=TRUE, aes(fill=key), alpha=0.3) +`

Comment: do you mean `geom_violin()`?

Comment: @roman: It looks so. But how to define it for both +/- `num_at_se` and +/- `num_wt_se` on the same chart?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming your dataset is called d and you don't `gather()`, how about this

```
ggplot(d, aes(x=hour, y=num_at)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = num_at + num_at_se, 
                  ymin = num_at - num_at_se), 
              fill = grey(0.5), alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line()
```

if you want to maintain the `gather()` step then try this

```
dd <- d %>% 
  gather(variable, value, -(1:2)) %>%
  separate(variable, c("type", "measurement"), "t") %>%
  spread(measurement, value)
colnames(dd)[4:5] <- c("value", "se")

ggplot(dd, aes(x=hour, y=value)) +
  geom_ribbon(aes(ymax = value + se, 
                  ymin = value - se, 
                  fill = type), 
              alpha = 0.5) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = type))
```

Comment: Should I add another `geom_ribbon` with some other color for the `num_wt_se`?

Comment: Instead of `geom_line()` I'd prefer to use `geom_smooth(span=0.3)`. Is it possible to also smooth the shape (i.e. `geom_ribbon`)? Also, I use `gather` to create separate line curves for `num_wt` and `num_at`. I would like to maintain this approach, or at least be able to show all the curves an shapes on a single chart.

Comment: if it were me, i would not smooth it purely for aesthetic effect. always show the data :-)
if you have a specific reason to 'model' the data first and plot the model then do that, i can help if you explain further what the intention is.

Comment: Thanks. I fit smoothing maximally to the original line, so that only zig-zags are actually smoothed.